# NativeScript Appim ERROR: This console is not interactive! Please export env PROJECT_TYPE

Tags: android, appium, nativescript

I have an error installing nativescript-dev-appium module in Windows 10 and NativeSript 8.2.0

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path [Path]\node_modules\nativescript-dev-appium
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./postinstall.js
npm ERR! This console is not interactive! Please export env PROJECT_TYPE!
npm ERR! ? What kind of project do you use? (Use arrow keys)
npm ERR! > javascript
npm ERR!   typescript
npm ERR!   angular
npm ERR!   vue
npm ERR!   shared-ng-project
```

I have setted the enviroment variable PROJECT_TYPE=angular manually and I had the same error

Expecting: nativescript-dev-appium installed and folder structure E2E created

Comment: Please format the Error to make it readable

Comment: sorry, first question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in postinstall script of this package and the real name of the environment variable it checks is not **PROJECT_TYPE** but rather **projectType**.

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-appium/blob/8744490b12d95bcd0478ba76f18a7aa60688b1f2/postinstall.js#L229

The other point is that "angular" value isn't what this script expects.

Here is the list of available values:

> js, tsc, ng, vue, sharedNg

So, it could be "projectType=ng" in your case.

There is one more thing this script will ask you after projectType has been found, and that is TESTING_FRAMEWORK.

Here is the list of values for that variable:

> mocha, jasmine, none

When both variables are set, it should pass the installation.